# Autorun without the popup window

Tags: usb, invisible, autorun

Soooo, I have some programs on my usb, and one of them is a virus I created.

I was wondering if there is a way to autorun it automaticaly without user input (I meant the popup)
like in the background (invisible)...

***(preferable windows xp, 7, 8, and 8.1)***

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autorun.inf feature was removed (for USB devices) and is not available in Window 7, 8 and 8.1.

On XP the normal stuff like this:

```
[autorun]
open=virus.exe
```

should work, but will display the Autoplay popup. I guess you can't disable this for security reasons.

- [MS' official Autorun documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)